# Error "The byte array is not a recognized imageformat" al leer una imagen de tipo byte[] desde la base de datos para itextSharp en C#

Tags: c#, itextsharp, asp.net-core-5.0

espero que puedan ayudarme. Le explico lo siguiente:
Obtengo la foto de la siguiente la siguiente foto desde la base de datos, la cual esta guardada como arreglo de byte:

```
      List<DevolImgModels> list_img = new List<DevolImgModels>();
            string sql = "";
            sql += " SELECT ";
            sql += " img.foto";
            sql += " FROM contratostimg img";
            conexion.conectar(constring);
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion.con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (MySqlDataReader d = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (d.Read())
                    {
                        list_img.Add(new DevolImgModels
                        {
                            foto = (byte[])d["foto"] //Meto la foto en una lista list_img, y foto es de tipo byte[]
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            conexion.cerrar();                     

//.....................
//..........

    Image foto = Image.GetInstance(fila.foto);
    PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(foto, true);
    c.Image.ScaleToFitHeight = false;
    table.AddCell(c);

....//definiciones de codigo para crear el pdf. Coloco los puntitos para ahorra código e ir directo al grano
...

foreach (var fila in list_img){
....
.....
Image foto =  = Image.GetInstance(fila.foto);
PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(foto, true);
c.Image.ScaleToFitHeight = false; 
table.AddCell(c);
```

}
Pero al pasar fila.foto(de tipo byte[]) a Image, da error, es decir en esta linea de codigo da el error:

```
     Image foto =  = Image.GetInstance(fila.foto);
```

Y el error que da es el siguiente:

**The byte array is not a recognized imageformat**

Me gustaría poder solucionarlo, si alguien tiene alguna idea o solución, se lo agradecería.

Información adicional, me he fijado que en los paquetes de dependencias hay una advertencia de itextsharp, puede ser que no sea compatible:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: El error te dice que el array de bytes no corresponde a ningún formato valido. Por lo tanto, yo lo primero que haría es analizar como se guarda la imagen y si en la BD quedó bien guardada

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy probando con NET 6 el itextsharp, pero en itextsharp con .net framework 4.5 no he tenido problemas

Comment: Dices que el mismo código funciona en .net 4.5, pero no lo hace en .net6?

Comment: claro, de hecho actualice la pregunta, colocando una foto donde sale una advertencia en las dependencias en itextsharp

Comment: Ahí está el problema esa librería no debe ser compatible, yo la instalé y me pasa lo mismo que a ti. Además dice que ya está desactualizada y que ahora se debe ocupar "iText 7" que vendría a ser la nueva versión